# Google Cloud Artifact Registry Maven publishing failure

Tags: java, maven, gradle, google-cloud-platform

I'm aware Maven artifacts for GCP Artifact Registry is in alpha, but still, I have this problem and I'm hoping someone can help me out.

I have created a repository for Maven. I have a service user with permissions to access it (Artifact Registry Reader and Artifact Registry Writer). I have downloaded the credentials file, and I have GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS pointing to it.

I know credentials file is good because if I mess with it it will tell me about missing fields, etc.

But when I do a simple `./gradlew clean` I get this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':plugin'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > 'org.gradle.api.credentials.Credentials org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.getConfiguredCredentials()'
```

Anybody knows what could possibly be wrong?

EDIT: Adding `build.gradle.kts` for reference:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.4.20"
    `java-gradle-plugin`
    `maven-publish`
    id("com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin") version "2.1.0"
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url = uri("artifactregistry://us-west1-maven.pkg.dev/glitchy-maven/repo")
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_15.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Align versions of all Kotlin components
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom"))
    // Use the Kotlin JDK 8 standard library.
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    // Use the Kotlin test library.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")
    // Use the Kotlin JUnit integration.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
}

group = "com.glitchybyte.gradle.plugin"
version = "1.0.0"

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        create("buildinfoplugin") {
            id = "com.glitchybyte.gradle.plugin.buildinfoplugin"
            implementationClass = "com.glitchybyte.gradle.plugin.buildinfoplugin.BuildInfoPlugin"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your gradle file?

Comment: Added my build.gradle.kts. Note that I haven't added `publishing` block yet. This error happens on adding the plugin and defining the repository.

Comment: How are you authenticated on the runtime environment? and can you try to upgrade the plugin version to 2.1.1 version?

Comment: I'm using a service account as described in the documentation. The problem described in my issue is now solved by upgrading to 2.1.1. But now I can't seem to get a project to USE an artifact in the repo. I'll make a new issue for that. If you make a post saying to upgrade I'll make that the answer to this one. Again, this all is alpha, no one will be using the old plugin now that the documentation has been updated, so I doubt this question will help anyone else. But no harm in completing the circle.